# Circle sprite creates 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect' error in Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a circle sprite that will be in a window that will have walls on the left and right of the screen.  I cannot get the `class Player` to work right as a circle but I can get it to work as a square.  After trying to fix this for 20-ish hours I am hell bent to make the circle work... Or at least understand why my code is failing.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (105,105,105)
red = (255,0,0)

class Barrier(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #Barriers will be walls and "floors"

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): #player will be a circle

    def __int__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill(white)

        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, black, (25, 25), 25, 0)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.barrier = None

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.barrier, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.barrier, False)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill(white)

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group() #wall will be a vertical Barrier

wall = Barrier(0,0,10,800,red)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Barrier(790,0,10,800,red)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

player = Player(50,50)
player.barrier = wall_list

all_sprite_list.add(player)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0

done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)

    all_sprite_list.update()

    screen.fill(white)
    all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

Full Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pyDump/FallGame/freeFALL.py", line 114, in <module>
    all_sprite_list.update()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 462, in update
    s.update(*args)
  File "D:/pyDump/FallGame/freeFALL.py", line 43, in update
    self.rect.x += self.change_x
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

For context, I'm using Pycharm and python 3.5 on a PC.  Thanks!

*edit- grammar

Comment: You misspelled "__init__" in your Player class...

Comment: You should submit that as the answer so I can give you the green check mark you deserve!

Answer (score 0):

In your Player class, you spelled init as int.  That means when the object is created, none of the code in that method runs.